# Instagram - Get Recently updated media (photos or videos)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there any API to get id's of ALL images or videos that are commented or liked after a certain timestamp.

Is there any API to get all comments of the profile without including the 'media-id' (image or video id)

Comment: The only API public known is the official Instagram API, which you are able to execute requests into the endpoints available by Instagram API and handle the returned data.
To get the id of all images/videos you have to make a request into this https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/ and according to the documentation there is no endpoint available to return all comments of the profile without including the media-id.

I encourage you to read the whole documentation at https://www.instagram.com/developer/

I wish this helps you in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no API to directly access the comments by time for a user profile.

You have first get all the media for a user:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Then for each media, get comments:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

use the `created_time` in the comments to filter out the latest comments, note that you only get the latest 150 comments for each of the media.